# Solving an array task python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array below that contains yields from cows totalled each day.

```
[5, 3, 7, 9, 3, 3, 7, 108, 66, 16, 5, 3, 7, 3]
```

There are two cows in the herd, and they have been milked twice a day, therefore leaving my array with 14 elements of which each element stands for a daily total milking yield and therefore there are seven elements for each element corresponding for yield totals for 7 days.

The format of my array is.

```
[Cow1Day1, Cow1Day2, Cow1Day3, Cow1Day4, Cow1Day5, Cow1Day6, Cow1Day7, Cow2Day1, Cow2Day2, Cow2Day3, Cow2Day4, Cow2Day5, Cow2Day6, Cow2Day7]
```

I need to find out which cow yields less than 12 liters for a span of 4 days or more. How do I do that?

Note: I can even have more cows in my herd all depending on the input of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
yields = [5, 3, 7, 9, 3, 3, 7, 108, 66, 16, 5, 3, 7, 3]
numOfCows = int(len(yields) / 7)       ## /7 as there are 7 days in a week

for i in range(numOfCows):   ## For every cow
    for j in range(4):       ## There are four possible spans to be checked
        span = yields[ (i * 7) + j  :  (i * 7) + j + 4 ]    ## Get the four-day period
        if sum(span) < 12:   ## If the sum of the span is smaller than 12 litres
            print("Cow " + str(i + 1))    ## Print the cow number
```

Comment: yields / 7 is not possible. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'. Even if you do len(yields) / 7, that might be a floating point and range will reject it.

Comment: On this line: span = numOfCows[ (i * 7) + j  :  (i * 7) + j + 4 ] you get TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. Perhaps replace numOfCows with yields.

Comment: @AshishAcharya Thanks again! I don't know how I didn't spot that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [5, 3, 7, 9, 3, 3, 7, 108, 66, 16, 5, 3, 7, 3]
```

First split your cow data to get a separate list of weekly yields for each cow, like so:

```
cows = [data[x:x+7] for x in range(0, len(data), 7)]
```

Output:

```
[[5, 3, 7, 9, 3, 3, 7], [108, 66, 16, 5, 3, 7, 3]]
```

Now, for each cow, figure out whether sum of any 4 day window is less than 12:

```
bad_yields = [any([sum(cow[n:4+n])<12 for n in range(len(cow)-4+1)]) for cow in cows]
```

Output:

```
[False, False]
```

Finally, print out which cows have yields less than 12

```
for idx, ylt12 in enumerate(bad_yields):
    if ylt12:
        print("Yield less than 12 for cow %d" % (idx + 1))
```